# How to get specific value/name using dimsav/laravel-translatable package

Tags: laravel

I have followed the [doc](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable). I created two tables:

1. countries
2. country_translations.

[image]

Now I changed the column `name => key` and `value` cause I can get the value (lang text) by query `key`.

Say for example :

```
$r = 'DE';//App::getLocale(); // 'fr'
$germany = Country::where('code', $r)->first();

// I want to get value where key= 'contacts-last-name'
$translation = $germany->translate($r, true)->where('key', 'contacts-last-name')->value;

print_r($translation);
exit("----");
```

I get:

```
ERROR: Undefined property
```

How may I get specific value using new query/sub query (key).

---

**For an Example here is my method and view**

Updated the method as below ::

```
$translation = $germany->translate($r, true)->where('key', 'contacts-last-name')->first();

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($translation->toArray()); exit("----");
```

and got the answer:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [country_id] => 83
    [key] => contacts-last-name
    [value] => Achternaam
    [locale] => DE

)
```

In view Page I have a form :

```
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{trans('labels.contacts-first-name')}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" required disabled>
        </div>

       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{trans('labels.contacts-last-name')}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control" disabled>
        </div>
```

for this one I have a question how may I pass translate data and make transable views all the time `{{trans('labels.contacts-last-name')}}`

Answer (score 0):

change your this line

```
$translation = $germany->translate($r, true)->where('key', 'contacts-last-name')->value;
```

to this, and then try it

```
$translation = $germany->translate($r, true)->where('key', 'contacts-last-name')->get();

print_r($translation);
exit("----");
```

**Updated**

in your view, `{{trans('labels.contacts-last-name')}}` this way means that you are trying to grab translation from your lang directory exists in your project, in actual this is manual file based/array (key/pair) way.

while you want Dynamic/DB based, you can do this

pass you `$translation` variable into your view, eg

```
return view('form-view', compact('translation'));
```

and then in your `view` you can do this.

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{$translation[0]->value}}</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" required disabled>
</div>

   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{$translation[1]->value}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control" disabled>
    </div>
```

Comment: :: It is working. Then how May I translate a form label or column name in view ? Would you please help me to get an example with method and views ?

Comment: Please add your `print_r()` dumped results in your question also add some of your form view structure in question, I will guide you

Comment: :: I have added a new section for better understanding into my question "For an Example here is my method and view" .. Please have a look and allow me to get your help.

Comment: please do this, and update your this result in your question....... 
`echo "<pre>";
print_r($translation->toArray());
exit("----");`

Comment: you have to comment out your these lines 
`print_r($translation); 
exit("----");`

Comment: I have add echo "<pre>"; print_r($translation->toArray()); exit("----");
In Section ::
**For an Example here is my method and view**

Comment: I am not getting your question

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like so:
`$translation = $germany->{'contacts-last-name:'.$r};`

https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable/blob/master/src/Translatable/Translatable.php#L153

Comment: :: Its returning NULL . Its not working. In doc its called magic method.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($translation->toArray()); exit("----");
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [country_id] => 83
    [key] => contacts-last-name
    [value] => Achternaam
    [locale] => DE
)
```